# Angular pipe calls httpclent twice

Tags: javascript, angular

Server returns json data (not an array). I use a pipe/map with http to retrieve the data. Somehow, the pipe always runs twice: first time - with empty json data, second time - the server code outputs the json data, but `catchError()` generates "unknown error". Below is the code snippet, please help.

```
export class DbstoreService {
  private apiURL: string;
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
       this.apiURL = environment.proxyPath;
  }

  getInfo()  {
     return this.http.get(`${this.apiURL}api/getInfo/5`)
     .pipe(
        map(response => response),
       catchError(this.handleError)
    )
    }
    private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error('handle Error: ' + error.toString());
    return throwError(() => error.toString() || 'Server error');
     }
}

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
... 
  constructor(
    private dbstoreService: DbstoreService
    )
  {
  }

  async getInfo()
  {
     await this.dbstoreService.getAgencyInfo().subscribe((data) => {});
         //  this.info.name = a.name;
 //  });
  }
}
```

Server code:

```
 public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
      {
     ...
        return Json(new { name = "testertester" });
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do.
There are two good ways to call an observable in your component:

1. Declaring the observable as a property in your Component class and calling it in your template using the async pipe.

   > ```
   > @Component({
   >   selector: 'app-component',
   >   template: '<div>Name: {{ agencyInfo | async }}</div>',
   > })
   > export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
   >   agencyInfo$ = this.dbstoreService.getAgencyInfo();
   >
   >   constructor(
   >     private dbstoreService: DbstoreService
   >     )
   >   {}
   > }
   > ```
2. Subcribing to the Observable in the component class and binding it to a local variable that will be used in the template.

   > ```
   > @Component({
   >   selector: 'app-component',
   >   template: '<div>Name: {{ name }}</div>',
   > })
   > export class AppComponent implements OnInit, onDestroy{
   >
   >   name: string;
   >   agencyInfoSub!: Subscription;
   >
   >   constructor(
   >     private dbstoreService: DbstoreService
   >     )
   >   {}
   >
   >   ngOnInit(): void {
   >     this.agencyInfoSub! = this.dbstoreService.getAgencyInfo().subscribe(data => {
   >       this.name = data;
   >     });
   >   }
   >
   >   ngOnDestroy(): void {
   >     this.agencyInfoSub!.unsubscribe();
   >   }
   > ```